# DIV isn't getting wider when inserting more text

Tags: html, css, wordpress, multiple-columns, horizontal-scrolling

I want to make a horizontal scrolled portfolio site, now the homepage works fine. But my biography page doesn't get wider when inserting more text.

I'll show you with an example:

1. This is how I want it to be when there are 2 columns of text; works fine. http://fjkip.nl/test/biografie.php
2. And this is what happens when there are 3 or more columns of text; the green background doesn't expand.
   http://fjkip.nl/test/biografie2.php

HTML:

```
<div id="content">

    <div id="scroll-wrapper2">

        <div id="post-text">

           *TEXT IN HERE*

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content
{
    height: 350px;
    overflow: auto;

}

#scroll-wrapper2
{
    white-space: no-wrap;
}

#post-text
{
    background-color: #00ff00;
    height: 275px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    -webkit-column-width: 20em;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like your HTML isn't formatted correctly, there are paragraphs of text outside of `p` tags, try formatting correctly first and see if that fixes it

Comment: `white-space: no-wrap;` isn't valid, it should be `nowrap`. But you don't want this, delete this line.

Comment: Set all the paragraphs inside the `p` tag. And deleted the `no-wrap`, I used it on the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `width` or `max-width` to your `#post-text` container, and adding the `overflow-x: scroll;` to your stylesheet. Not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but this keeps the content on the page. The `width` you apply will need to be changed depending on your site settings, but this is the general idea.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gQ8uL/)**

```
#post-text
{
  background-color: #00ff00;
  height: 275px;
  max-width: 500px; /* change to desired width */
  overflow-x: scroll; /* added so scrollbar happens in this container */
  font-size: 10pt;
  -webkit-column-width: 20em;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

Comment: I want the scrollbar in the #content container. So the squares on the left will also move. Like how it works on this page: http://fjkip.nl/test/home.php

Oh, and I don't know the width, this has to depand on how many text is inside.

Comment: Not really, I want the scrollbar on the position where it is on the example: http://fjkip.nl/test/biografie2.php.
But if that isn't possible I have to do it like this.

Comment: You can try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gQ8uL/5/). If you want to remove the background color below the text and boxes, you'll likely need to add another wrap just inside `#content` and apply the `background-color` there instead.

Comment: When I do that the `background-color` is again not as wide as the text. http://fjkip.nl/test/biografie2.php

Comment: You didn't change all the CSS from the fiddle I previously posted. Move that background-color to `#content`, per the fiddle. As I mentioned before, if you don't want the background color to go all the way down to the slider, then you can add another wrapper just inside `#content` and use the `background-color` there.

Comment: I copied all the code from the second Fiddle you posted. Then added an another wrapper inside the `#content` called `#wrap-color` and only set the `background-color` of that div. And I get the same problem.
The only solution I could imagine is to take your Fiddle and add a white div on the bottom of `#content`.

Answer (score 0):

setting `overflow: scroll` to `#post-text` should get you there.